# SQL compare dates without time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 12.6.  I would like to compare two dates in a WHERE clause, without the time.

e.g.

```
WHERE flight_date = (?1)
```

The flight_date is for example '2022-02-09 11:21:23' and the parameter is '2022-02-09 11:22:54', but I want them to be equal because they are on the same day (ignore the time).

I am using Java11 with Hibernate JPA.

```
        java.util.Date flightDate = ...
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter(1, flightDate);
        List<Long> tripIds = query.getResultList();
```

Error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: function to_date(timestamp without time zone,
> unknown) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and
> argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to cast the timestamp to a date:

```
where cast(flight_date as date) = ?1
```

However that won't be able to make use of an index on `flight_date`. If you need the performance, a range query is better:

```
where flight_date >= ?1
  and flight_date < ?1 + interval '1 day';
```